# How to ask for a yes/no answer within a loop?

Tags: c#, console

I'm trying to write a simple console game application & I'm running into some idk moments. Okay, so in the code I'm trying to get a Y/N input and have start the game over if Y, or Exit if N. I'd love to hear some various solutions & there's bonus <3 for a coding sample that assigns random door number every time the game is started or played.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;

namespace Desicions
// Typo I know.
{
    class Program
    {
    static void Main(string[] args)
      {

        bool WrongInput = true;

        while (WrongInput)
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("Would you perfer what's behind door 1, 2, or 3?");
            string userValue = Console.ReadLine();
            if (userValue == "1")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You won a new car!");
                WrongInput = false;
            }
            else if (userValue == "2")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You won a boat!");
                WrongInput = false;
            }
            else if (userValue == "3")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Aww, you did not win this time please play again.");
                WrongInput = false;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please choose door number 1, 2, or 3. Press Enter to return to game.");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Would you like to play again? (Y/N)");

        while ((Console.ReadLine() == "Y") || (Console.ReadLine() == "y"))
            //Should I use this instead?
            //while String.Equals(Console.ReadLine(), "y", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
            //if so, why?
        {
            //What goes here for (Y)/(y) input to return into top of while (WrongInput) loop?
            Console.WriteLine("Currently in Dev [:");
        }
        while ((Console.ReadLine() == "N") || (Console.ReadLine() == "n"))
        {
            //I would like for a (N)/(n) input to WriteLine("Exiting game..."); Thread.Sleep(2000); then exit. Solutions plz por favor?
        }


        //BONUS c# <3 for code sample for setting doors numbers randomly!

        Console.ReadLine();

    }
}
```

}

Comment: See my edit on how to pick a random door :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a somewhat robust approach to tackle this problem:

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Choose 1, 2, 3 or X to exit.");

                // read input
                var s = Console.ReadLine();

                // shall we exit ?
                if (s != null && s.Trim().Equals("X", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Bye bye !");
                    break;
                }

                // user picked an activity
                int result;
                if (!int.TryParse(s, out result)) continue; // failed to read input


                // at this point, do something interesting
                Console.WriteLine("You selected : " + result);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you'll see,

- it won't matter whether user typed in upper case or lower case, with leading/trailing spaces -> the approach handles that
- you will compare against a number the user has choosen VS a `string` (better)
- etc ...

Go on and improve on that :)

**EDIT : choose a random door**

```
const int maxDoors = 3;
var doors = new Dictionary<int, string>
{
    {0, "Door 1"},
    {1, "Door 2"},
    {2, "Door 3"}
};
var random = new Random();
while (true)
{
    // integrate this inside the previous example loop

    var door = random.Next(maxDoors);
    var doorName = doors[door];
    Console.WriteLine("You have chosen the door: " + doorName);
}
```

Comment: After thinking on how to use this implementation, this sample answers the Y/N question while ignoring the upper/lower issue way better than I honestly thought possible. Aybe, I learned something new just now, Thank You.

Comment: Aybe,you're just a delight. I'm just getting back to SO & saw this edit & immediately had value for it! I need to get my rank up so I can +1 you

Comment: Sorry mate. Upped you up from -1 to 0 but that is all I can do:/

Answer (score 0):

You would benefit greatly from simply doing Console.ReadLine().ToLower() (Or ToUpper()), to ignore any case issues.

As for what you currently have, by saying `(Console.ReadLine() == "foo" || Console.ReadLine() == "bar")`, you are calling the command to take in user input twice, meaning the user will need to input whether they'd like to play again twice before you break into while loop.

As for your random door number, check out `System.Random`, and assign it to a variable at the start of your game.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random(v=vs.110).aspx

Also, rather than calling an empty `Console.WriteLine();`, simply add in `"\n"` to your string to create a newline.

And finally, it's "prefer," not "perfer."

Comment: I appreciate the sample on how to force the input to upper & lower and thank you for the explaining my mistake on calling the input twice, I was wondering about that... And so much <3 for the reference, I have some reading to do. As for `\n`, I did some research, since I'm in a windows environment should I explicitly use `\r\n` or support all OS environments by using `Environment.NewLine`?

Answer (score 0):

I saw this on the top questions, and I may be stepping over my own limit. Currently learning Java. Just trying to help, sorry If I am of no use.

But couldn't you use a `do while` loop and towards the end ask for input from the user. Perform the check at the end with the do while loop, if Y/yes continue if N/no don't?

chicken scratch:

```
do
{
 //Game code
 //ask for input
} while input == Y | input == y
```